# Typical CSS Lib used with Angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

hi all things done with jquery can be done with `angularjs` and also i heard it can be done more easily with angular. but have the following questions?

1. for ASP MVC provides `unobstrusive` validations of forms' controls, since `angularjs` is not jquery and not commonly used with jquery does the `unobstrusive` validations done through Angular or i have to use some other?
2. Is Bootstrap still used with Angular as the primary look-and-feel library?
3. please provide some good resource links for `AngularJs-ui`, data binding etc just as they have resource links for jquery

Comment: Whatever css framework you use has nothing to do with angular. Also angular has built in validation. Please do some basic research before asking questions like this

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure about that but AngularJS is commonly used with jQuery for directives etc. You can use Angular without jQuery as Angular comes with it's own lighter version of it. But unobtrusive should work alongside Angular.
2. Yes, Bootstrap is commonly used for styling. You can also check out [AngularUI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which has AngularJS support builtin and a nice set of extra tools.
3. Check out their Github pages for each project, it contains a bunch of useful info. https://github.com/angular-ui/